# How to use JS to move the box left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my css and html for the weight and arrows. I want to make the weight to move left and right by clicking arrows. Please help me to find js.

```css
.container {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 255, 3.5, 0.4);
}
.arrow {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.right {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
}
.board {
  transform-origin: 50%, 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ff0;
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  left: 25px;
}
.weight {
  transform-origin: -50% -50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="arrow left"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
  <div class="arrow right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
  <div class="scale">
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="gravity">
      <div class="weight"></div>
      <div class="board"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have HTML and CSS but would like to know to make jS how to make move this weight right and left by clicking the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow left" onclick="arrowLeft"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
<div class="arrow right" onclick="arrowRight"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
<div class="weight" id="weight"></div>
```

JS:

```
var left = 0
var right = 0
function arrowLeft() {
   let x = document.getElementById("weight")
   left = left + 25 + "px"
   x.style.left = left;
}
function arrowRight() {
   let x = document.getElementById("weight")
   right = right + 25 + "px"
   x.style.left = right;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but somehow, the arrow is not working to make the box move... Is there any other way? like finding the current value of the weight(box) and subtracting any px from there to move back and forth by clicking the part of arrows?

Comment: @Illyo im not sure, I was on my phone when I wrote this answer so I couldn't actually test it. Furthermore, I am still quite new to coding so I just wrote what I would try if I was trying to make what you were making.